# ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE on certain webpages using chrome on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

I have a weird issue. I can't access some webpages (e.g. youtube) through chrome on my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. I can access the webpages fine with firefox, just not with chrome. Chrome returns an "ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE" error. Any ideas what I might do to resolve this?

To clarify, I can access most webpages just fine, the only one I've encountered this error with is youtube. I've tried googling the issue but all the posts I've found were windows related or regarding the youtube app.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the command line and type

```
cd /etc
sudo nano resolv.conf
```

Add the following nameservers:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

- Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- Press <kbd>Y</kbd>
- Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Type the following command

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

I guess this should solve your query.

Comment: Could you please explain, what exactly are we trying to do with these commands??