# Network issues Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, server

I'm still new to Linux and I have been running a Ubuntu server for almost 2 years now. The machine itself is a HP ProLiant DL160 G6 and it had been shut off for about 6 months while I found a replacement fan. Upon firing it back up the ethernet connection has been having some issues. It didn't work for a day or so and then it worked for one day and has not worked since. Upon further inspection I noticed that the connection said "unmanaged" I don't know what that means, but I did some research and was able to fix that and now the connection shows up normally. My new issue is now I'm unable to access websites and my docker containers also do not have network access. I can still remotely log into the machine from my computer on the same network, but for some reason I cannot access certain sites like this one from the server. I get a
[ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W1vN.png) when trying to access some sites

Comment: Did you check: https://askubuntu.com/questions/925286/err-address-unreachable-on-certain-webpages-using-chrome-on-ubuntu-16-04 ?  It lack explanation, but...

Comment: " "unmanaged" I don't know what that means, but I did some research and was able to fix that" How? Please edit your question to show the result of: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: To fix the unmanged part I tried what was recommended here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039233/no-wired-connection-wired-unmanaged-ubuntu-18-04

The result of `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` is this
`# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp6s0f0:
      dhcp4: true
    enp6s0f1:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2`

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Please don't add details to comments. There's not enough room and you can't use formatting tools to add the information in a presentable way. Edit your question and provide clear/complete details about what you've already done. Please be thorough and use formatting tools so we can parse the information and distinguish details like commands and terminal output from surrounding text.

Comment: Your fix was to make a change to Network Manager. It usually isn't installed in a server in favor of netplan. Are you running NM? If so, we'll need to amend netplan accordingly.

Comment: something with DNS? If you add 8.8.8.8?